# app engine search api: Two variable query?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-search-api

I am building an app where professionals can get job offers from nearby clients , and the professional can configure the `max_radius` so he will not receive offers further away from him than the `max_radius`.

so I built a simple `Index` which contains documents with the fields: `location : GeoField` and 'max_radius : NumberField' , each document represents a professional and `max_radius` different for each one since they configure it themselves.

when I try this query: `distance(location , geopoint(22.0,11.3)) < 100000` it works as expected.

when I try: `max_radius < 450000` , works as expected.

but when I try: `distance(location , geopoint(22.0,11.3)) < max_radius`
i suddenly get: `ValueError: could not convert string to float: max_radius`.

fiddling around a bit more , I began to question: 
is it not possible to make multiple variable queries , or am I doing it wrong ?

Can anyone shed some light on this , and maybe suggest a way to achieve my goal ?

Comment: `distance(location , geopoint(22.0,11.3)) < float(max_radius)` be sure that max_radius is actually a number.